# Log4Net: RollingFileAppender, new instead of override

Tags: c#, file, logging, log4net

I'm using Log4Net to log to files. I wish to let the logs be seperated by date so i use a datepattern:

```
<DatePattern value=".yy-MM-dd.'xml'" />
```

However, if the program is shut down and started again, the same file is either overwridden, or appended to (by `AppendToFile` property). I would like that if the program has previously been started on the same day, another file with a incremented count be created instead.

The directory might look like this:

```
Logs/
  log.15-01-03.xml
  log.15-01-04.xml
  log.15-01-04.0.xml
  log.15-01-04.1.xml  //program opened 3 times on the 4th of jan. '15
  log.15-01-05.xml
```

So, roll on date and count on session. Any Ideas?

Also, if i would like backup files of all logs, should i use a second appender, to a `Logs/Backup/` directory, or is there a fancy way in Log4Net?

my RollingFileAppender is currently setup like this:

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender"
          type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <File value="Log/log" />
  <DatePattern value=".yy-MM-dd.'xml'" />
  <Layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayout" />
  <RollingStyle value="Date" />
  <MaxSizeRollBackups value="2147483647" />
  <CountDirection value="0"/>
  <StaticLogFileName value="false"/>
  <Encoding value="Unicode"/>
  <ImmediateFlush value ="true"/>
  <PreserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>
</appender>
```

Comment: Not exactly answering the question but if the purpose is to keep history of the log files then changing the DatePattern to   <DatePattern value=".yy-MM-dd.HH:mm:ss.'xml'" /> will serve the purpose

Comment: Just tested, and this just make the roll happen every minute :(

Comment: Change <RollingStyle value="Once" /> this will stop it from creating file every second. Hope it helps

Comment: @Bayern it will also stop the file from rolling, and break the file naming - the datePattern is only used for rollingStyle Date (or rollingStyle Composite)

Comment: After having analyzed the source code of the RollingFileAppender (damm! 1700+ lines), the issue lies in two places:

**1.** During init when the directory is scanned, it uses a wildcard search, which don't take into account the date and count appends, so no files are ever found. Value need to be changed from `".*"` to `"*"`. 

**2.** When the correct number of files are found, it will now replace (if `AppendToFile = false`) the last item found. Now it just needs to increment the counter before deciding to, which i succeds by moving the increment from `RollOverSize` to `RollOverRenameFiles`.